# form_for NoMethod Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nomethoderror

I keep getting a NoMethodError for my form_for

This is in my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 6 %>
  <%f.submit 'Save' %>
```

and in new.html.erb

```
<h1> New Booking </h1>  
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and the end result:  NoMethodError in Bookings#new appears.

(P.S this question is a bit off-topic but how would I go in making a form input for selecting a TO and FROM date (in order of month:day:year)?

Comment: Can you specify where the error is? (You probably didn't define `@booking` or something like that. PS: Use 2 datepickers with custom names for input and in your controller use the params they turn in.

Comment: I used on "def new @booking = Booking.new" on the bookings controller. and the error was "undefined method `content' for #<Booking id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"

Comment: Did you migrate? It seems your bookings don't have a content column.

Comment: I did proceed to run rake db:migrate and still have the error. How would I add a content column? I figured :content was a built-in syntax.

Comment: Migrations make your models have database representations. Check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html. I'll post a short answer for a short term solution (you should really learn this).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you don't haven't migrated your model, so it only has an id and timestamps. Just create a new migration (or edit the existing if you don't mind resetting the db, but it isn't a good practice).

Run in terminal:

```
rails generate migration AddContentToBookings content:text
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Be sure to check out [Rails Migration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I will read that migration guide. While the <%= f.label :content %> did work, the "<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 6 %>" did not seem to.

Comment: Rails for Zombies is great to start learning rails (railsforzombies.org/‎) There you can learn the framework layers and such. GL & HF.